# How do we extract the status code from dojo.io.iframe.send call?

Tags: javascript, dojo

How do we extract the status code from dojo.io.iframe.send call ? I'm viewing the properties of the ioArgs parameter and not able to see the status code in it. I guess this does not have a xhr property, since the output is undefined when I try to print it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can not extract the status code from `dojo.io.iframe.send` calls. You can only tell whether the request is succeeded or not. If it's successed, the `load` callback is invoked, otherwise, `error` callback is invoked.

`dojo.io.iframe.send` creates an iframe to send the request. The browser may not provide a way to monitor the status of iframe requests. What dojo does is to try to extract some data from the iframe DOM when the iframe is loaded. If the data can be extracted successfully, then the request is succeeded, otherwise it failed.

Make sure the target url of `dojo.io.iframe.send` calls returns the correct format that dojo can understand. For example,

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
    <textarea>result data</textarea>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I was under the impression that error callback for iframes is invoked for HTTP status codes (similar to xhr calls). Now, I understand that it is invoked when dojo is unable to extract the response from the iframe DOM. Thanks for the info. The Dojo documentation does not throw any light on this behavior. The iframe examples also handle the load and error callback without highlighting this deviation.